# API Platform - Adding new entity with subresource

Tags: api-platform.com

As far as I can see this isn't possible but I thought I'd ask in case I've missed something.

I have 2 entities, Rule and Condition

One Rule can have many Conditions

What I'm trying to achieve is adding a new Rule with one or more Conditions in a single request

I've tried the following via POST

```
{
  "property": "id",
  "conditions": [
    {
        "position": 1
    }
  ],
  "title": "getId",
  "position": 1
}
```

Conditions have a rule_id column, but I obviously can't set it at this point as it hasn't been created yet

That request gives me the error

```
Nested documents for attribute "conditions" are not allowed. Use IRIs instead.
```

Of course, I can't use an IRI because I haven't created the condition yet, and I can't create the condition first as it would fail foreign key checks

So am I right in thinking this isn't possible or am I just doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the same serialization group to both the `Rule` and `Condition` classes, as explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations).

Also you must add the `cascade={"persist"}` attribute to the `@OneToMany` annotation of the `Rule::conditions` property.

Something like that:

```php
// src/EntityRule.php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: RuleRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        "post" => [
            "denormalization_context" => [ "groups" => ["write:rule"]]
        ]
    ]
)]
class Rule
{
    // ...
    
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: "rule", targetEntity: Condition::class, cascade: ["persist"])]
    #[Groups(["write:rule"])]
    /**
     * @var Condition[]
     */
    private Collection $conditions;

    // ...
}
```

```php
// src/Entity/Condition.php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ConditionRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        "post" => [
            "denormalization_context" => ["groups" => ["write:condition"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
)]
class Condition
{
    // ...

    #[ORM\Column(nullable=false, unique=false)]
    #[Groups(["write:condition", "write:rule"])]
    private int $position;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. A note in case anyone else reads this, I had to change the cascade part to `cascade={"persist"}`

Comment: I read documentation multiple times and it's not as your source code. Your example works but this one of api-platform does not (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#denormalization).